# Deserialize json that has some property name starting with a number

Tags: c#, json.net

JSON data looks like this

```
[
    {
        "market_id": "21",
        "coin": "DarkCoin",
        "code": "DRK",
        "exchange": "BTC",
        "last_price": "0.01777975",
        "yesterday_price": "0.01770278",
        "change": "+0.43",
        "24hhigh": "0.01800280",
        "24hlow": "0.01752015",
        "24hvol": "404.202",
        "top_bid": "0.01777975",
        "top_ask": "0.01790000"
    }
]
```

Notice these 3 properties here 24high, 24hhlow, and 24hvol
how do you make a class for that. I need all those properties by the way, not just those 3 properties I mentioned.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You should use JSON.NET or similar library that offers some more advanced options of deserialization. With JSON.NET all you need is adding JsonProperty attribute and specify its custom name that appears in resulting JSON. Here is the example:

```
   public class MyClass
   {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "24hhigh")]
        public string Highest { get; set; }
        ...
```

Now to deserialize:

```
    string jsonData = ...    
    MyClass deserializedMyClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(jsonData);
```

Comment: Thanks for that "JsonProperty"

Comment: To deserialize he would need `JsonConvert.Deserialize<List<MyClass>>(jsonData)` because the JSON represents an array, not a single object.

Comment: You save my lots of time.

Comment: in my case, the property represents some year, so the name isn't fixed, example: `"serie": { "2021" : "85541" }`. In this json 2021 is the year, how to deserialize in this case?

Answer (score 3):

For .NET Core 3.0 and beyond, you can now use the `System.Text.Json` namespace. If you are using this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    ...
    [JsonPropertyName("24hhigh")]
    public string twentyFourhhigh { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

You can use `JsonPropertyName` Attribute.