# JSON change value

Tags: c#, json

I have a JSON value like this

`{"$id":"649271776","$type":"outdoorgame","Overs":50,"Balls":6,"TeamName":"TestTeam"}`

I wrote a C# code like this to change the value of Overs from 50 to 10

```
var jsonString = sSession.GameState; //this is the value {"$id":"649271776","$type":"outdoorgame","Overs":50,"Balls":6,"TeamName":"TestTeam"}
dynamic jsonObject = 
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString);
jsonObject.Overs = 10;
var modifiedJsonString = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonObject);
```

This code is changing the value of Overs from 50 to 10. The problem I am facing when I use the above code modifiedJsonString is missing these two values

`"$id":"649271776","$type":"outdoorgame"`

giving the output as `{Overs":10,"Balls":6,"TeamName":"TestTeam"}` I want `$id` and `$type` also in the modifiedJsonString.

I want modifiedJsonString like this `{"$id":"649271776","$type":"outdoorgame","Overs":10,"Balls":6,"TeamName":"TestTeam"}`

Can anyone tell me how to solve this problem

Comment: Please format the JSON as well!

Comment: Actually JSON is correct only, I guess something has to do with $id and $type, so have to do the code differently (not sure)

Comment: How was the JSON serialised in the first place?

Comment: After modifying the overs I am Serialising like this var modifiedJsonString = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonObject);

Comment: I'm asking you so that the question is more readable!

Comment: Before Serializing the jsonObject the values are correct, after the Serializing the jsonObject then only $id and $type disappears

Comment: Where does this JSON come from in the first place? How is it created?

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24218536/deserialize-json-that-has-some-property-name-starting-with-a-number, when you deserialize the object those properties disappear because they start with `$`

Comment: Actually JSON values come from the client application, I request the server with the above values to change the Overs, after changing server will send it back to client. In server I am storing all the actions of a game

Comment: You miss my point, how is this JSON created by the server? Do you have that code?

Comment: Its a big code DavidG

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `$id` and `$type` are not valid identifiers, and can't appear as members of the returned dynamic object built by the JSON serializer. As in gldraphael's answer, the solution is to create your own concrete class to hold the deserialized object; for the properties whose names start with `$` you'll need to use `JsonPropertyAttribute` to remap the names:

```
public class GameState
{
    [JsonProperty("$id")] public string ID { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("$type")] public string Type { get; set; }
    int Overs { get; set; }
    int Balls { get; set; }
    public string TeamName { get; set; }
}
```

Further, Json.NET [treats `$type` as a special property name](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeTypeNameHandling.htm) and this interferes with proper deserialization of your object. To get around this, we must use the `MetadataPropertyHandling.Ignore` serializer setting.

Thus you can deserialize, modify and re-serialize like this:

```
string jsonString = "{\"$id\":\"649271776\",\"$type\":\"outdoorgame\",\"Overs\":50,\"Balls\":6,\"TeamName\":\"TestTeam\"}";
JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings() { MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.Ignore };
GameState jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GameState>(jsonString, settings);
jsonObject.Overs = 10;
var modifiedJsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonObject);
```

[See it in action](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hG7lDX).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `JToken` to handle this.

`using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;`

```
var jsonString = "{\"$id\":\"649271776\",\"$type\":\"outdoorgame\",\"Overs\":50,\"Balls\":6,\"TeamName\":\"TestTeam\"}";
JToken jsonObject = JToken.Parse(jsonString);
jsonObject["Overs"] = 10;
var modifiedJsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonObject);

// In case one wanted to update the $type and $id fields
jsonObject["$type"] = "asdf";
jsonObject["$id"] = 123456;
var modifiedJsonString2 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonObject);
```

Will result in:
modifiedJsonString --> `{"$id":"649271776","$type":"outdoorgame","Overs":10,"Balls":6,"TeamName":"TestTeam"}`

And if you needed to update `$id` and `$type`, that is possible, too.
modifiedJsonString2 -->
`{"$id":123456,"$type":"asdf","Overs":10,"Balls":6,"TeamName":"TestTeam"}`

Demo on .NET Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/a370Mv

Comment: But you are just creating static values here, this doesn't keep the original values.

Comment: I am demonstrating that one can also update the `$id` and `$type` as well.

Comment: But how would you keep the original values? This code just makes up new ones.

Comment: This worked Stringfellow... I want to approve your code but I don't have the enough reputation(I am new user) so unable to approve your code. Your code worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use a concrete class. You'll need to annotate the fields with $ prefixes manually. Eg:

```
public class Example
{
    public string Field { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("$type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

[Here's a working example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lBxuED).

In your case the class will look something like:

```
public class ObjName
{
    [JsonProperty("$id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("$type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public int Overs { get; set; }
    public int Balls { get; set; }
    public string TeamName { get; set; }
}
```

(Just be mindful of the property case).

Comment: This won't work, the `$id` and `$type` properties are special values.

Comment: @TypeIA Exactly, because they are special values used by JSON.Net which is why they occur at the start of the JSON. Look up `TypeNameHandling` (and are you now saying that you *didn't* try it out earlier...? :))

Comment: Always good to learn new things, and there's always more to learn!

Comment: @DavidG Luckily the authors did the right thing and provided an option to control this behavior. Thus, it works how we tell it to work. I have posted a more thorough answer with this information. I will also do some pollution control and delete all my previous comments here.