# Parse JSON with numeric key c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, json.net

I have an issue where an API i am trying to consume in .NET is using numeric keys. I have provided a sample of the JSON below.

```
{
"com": {
            "categories": [
                "gTLD",
                "Popular"
            ],
            "addons": {
                "dns": true,
                "email": true,
                "idprotect": true
            },
            "group": "hot",
            "register": {
                "1": "11.99",
                "2": "23.98",
                "3": "35.97",
                "4": "47.96",
                "5": "59.95",
                "6": "71.94",
                "7": "83.93",
                "8": "95.92",
                "9": "107.91",
                "10": "119.90"
            },
            "transfer": {
                "1": "11.99",
                "2": "23.98",
                "3": "35.97",
                "4": "47.96",
                "5": "59.95",
                "6": "71.94",
                "7": "83.93",
                "8": "95.92",
                "9": "107.91",
                "10": "119.90"
            },
            "renew": {
                "1": "11.99",
                "2": "23.98",
                "3": "35.97",
                "4": "47.96",
                "5": "59.95",
                "6": "71.94",
                "7": "83.93",
                "8": "95.92",
                "9": "107.91",
                "10": "119.90"
            },
            "grace_period": {
                "days": 30,
                "price": "£0.00"
            },
            "redemption_period": null
        }
    }
```

I am trying to extract the register prices out of the JSON in Razor to use in a table, however i just can't seem to access the values.

The Razor code:

```
var client = new RestClient("JSON_URL");
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(new RestRequest());
var o = JObject.Parse(response.Content);

@foreach (JProperty child in o["pricing"])
{
    <strong>@child.Name</strong>
    foreach (JObject ext in child.Children())
    {
        foreach (var property in ext["register"].Select(f => f.ToObject<GetDomainPricing>()))
        {
            @property
        }
    }
}
```

And the associated Model:

```
namespace TH.Models
{
    public class GetDomainPricing
    {
        public string Price { get; set; }
    }
}
```

After a week of battling with this error, the message i have ended up on is:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Unexpected token while deserializing object: PropertyName. Path 'pricing.com.register.1', line 1, position 243.
```

So at this point i am in need of some help, i don't have access to the JSON to change its format, but a link to the documentation is below:
[GetTldPricing - WHMCS Developer Documentation](https://developers.whmcs.com/api-reference/gettldpricing/)

All their examples are using PHP which looks like it doesn't have this issue.

---

## Solution

For anyone else trying to work out how to parse dynamic JSON with numeric keys, my answer is below.

Model:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace TerrabitHost.Models
{
    public class Addons
    {
        public bool dns { get; set; }
        public bool email { get; set; }
        public bool idprotect { get; set; }
    }

    public class GracePeriod
    {
        public int days { get; set; }
        public string price { get; set; }
    }

    public class Pricing
    {
        public Extensions Tld { get; set; }
    }
    public class Extensions
public class Extensions
{
    public List<string> categories { get; set; }
    public Addons addons { get; set; }
    public string group { get; set; }
    public Prices register { get; set; }
    public Prices transfer { get; set; }
    public Prices renew { get; set; }
    public GracePeriod grace_period { get; set; }
    public object redemption_period { get; set; }
}

    public class Register
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "1")]
        public string One { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "2")]
        public string Two { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "3")]
        public string Three { get; set; }
    }

    public class GetDomainPricing
    {
        public Pricing[] Pricing { get; set; }
    }
    public class JsonBody
    {
        public Dictionary<string, Extensions> Pricing { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Razor View:

```
@{
    var client = new RestClient("JSON_URL");
    IRestResponse response = client.Execute(new RestRequest());
    JsonBody json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonBody>(response.Content);
}

@foreach (var ext in json.Pricing)
{
<strong>@ext.Key</strong>
@ext.Value.register.One);
}
```

Comment: [*How to I parse JSON in C#?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6620165/463206)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to deal with these is to deserialise them as `Dictionary<int, string>`. For example, using the following classes:

```
public class Addons
{
    public bool dns { get; set; }
    public bool email { get; set; }
    public bool idprotect { get; set; }
}

public class GracePeriod
{
    public int days { get; set; }
    public string price { get; set; }
}

public class Com
{
    public List<string> categories { get; set; }
    public Addons addons { get; set; }
    public string group { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<int, string> register { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<int, string> transfer { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<int, string> renew { get; set; }
    public GracePeriod grace_period { get; set; }
    public object redemption_period { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Com com { get; set; }
}
```

You can now deserialise with this code:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```

Comment: I'll post up my answer shortly, but i combined this with bzier's answer and made it dynamic

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the question/answer here: [Deserialize json that has some property name starting with a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24218536/deserialize-json-that-has-some-property-name-starting-with-a-number)

You will likely need to deserialize the JSON into an instance of a class you define. You can map the property names from the JSON to valid C# property names.

Borrowing/adapting the example from the referenced answer (credit to Borys Generalov),

```
   public class MyClass
   {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "1")]
        public string One { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "2")]
        public string Two { get; set; }
        ...
```

Now to deserialize:

```
    string jsonData = ...    
    MyClass deserializedMyClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(jsonData);
```

Comment: @DavidG's answer looks more appropriate for your use case

Comment: Thanks for that it's useful to know if i need it, but i went with Davids answer :)

Comment: I'll post up my solution shortly, but i ended up combining this with Davids answer